# Trying to remember a book I read where everyone moves to Venus

Tags: story-identification

In this book (I don't remember much), Venus came after Earth, almost as the way many people view heaven. Earth was only there to round off the rough edges of people. I don't remember much more, but I think Earth was broken or we killed it or something, so everyone found a way to go to Venus. Maybe. Definitely was a black book with pink writing. Sound familiar?

Comment: You mean the pages were black and printed in pink?

Comment: More likely that's the style of the cover, but goodness knows...

Comment: In *Last and First Men*, the Fifth Men migrate to Venus when Earth becomes uninhabitable.